# Cannot resolve class dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to fix an issue for hours but nothing seems to work.I tried everything available online. I am using Intellij IDEA. I am using a Maven project. I have created `hibernate.cfg.xml` with following content

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Following line is throwing an error that cannot resolve class `dialect`

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
```

My *External Libraries* structure looks like this.

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the exact and complete exception stack trace.

Comment: I am not sure but for sometime it was showing this error. `File is not configured as hibernate facet`

Comment: @QasimAli do you get the error only in pom.xml highlighting or when app is running?

Comment: @CrazyCoder only on hibernate.cfg.xml highlighting. I did not try to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem was Intellij IDEA was not able to download maven files for Hibernate. I used [maven repository](https://mvnrepsitory.com) for adding the repository.